# Image compression in Android?

Tags: android, image-compression

I want to implement Whatsapp image compression in my andorid app.
I am suing following code in onActivityResult function to save my image:

```
Uri photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, 
getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", getCameraFile());

String uri = compressImage(photoUri.toString());
```

This is whatsapp compressImage function:

```
 public String compressImage(String imagePath) {
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);

    int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
    int actualWidth = options.outWidth;

    float imgRatio = (float) actualWidth / (float) actualHeight;
    float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

    if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
        if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {
            imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
            actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);
            actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
        } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
            imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
            actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
            actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
        } else {
            actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
            actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;

        }
    }

    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    options.inDither = false;
    options.inPurgeable = true;
    options.inInputShareable = true;
    options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

    try {
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();

    }
    try {
        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
    float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
    float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
    float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

    Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
    scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
    canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

    if(bmp!=null)
    {
        bmp.recycle();
    }

    ExifInterface exif;
    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(imagePath);
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        if (orientation == 6) {
            matrix.postRotate(90);
        } else if (orientation == 3) {
            matrix.postRotate(180);
        } else if (orientation == 8) {
            matrix.postRotate(270);
        }
        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0, scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    String filepath = getFilename();
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(filepath);

       //write the compressed bitmap at the destination specified by filename.
        scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return filepath;
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }
    final float totalPixels = width * height;
    final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;

    while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
        inSampleSize++;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

public String getFilename() {
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/Android/data/"
            + context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
            + "/Files/Compressed");

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        mediaStorageDir.mkdirs();
    }

    String mImageName="IMG_"+ String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) +".jpg";
    String uriString = (mediaStorageDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/"+ mImageName);;
    return uriString;

}

}
```

But my app crashes when i try to perform this function. While debugging i saw that after line:

```
  Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageUri, options);
```

bmp is equals null, and that outHeight and outWidth from Options are equals 0.
Please help, I am struggling with this problem for few days and i can't find solution..

Comment: there's no `imageUri` anywhere in your code. make sure `imageUri` contains the path to the image file, and not some garbage.